# How would you utilize NLP for this situation?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am working on a project that involves pulling data from a free response section of a survey and matching it to one or more pre-determined categories.

For example: someone who took the survey could input "smoking?" or "history of smoking" or "history of tobacco use" and the program would link their answer to the "History of Smoking" category.

There are many different categories and the users will input responses for multiple categories inside the same survey input box.

I am very new to machine learning and natural language processing and I was wondering what steps or algorithms would be used for a problem like this.  Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. This looks like to me a regular case of text classification, i.e. supervised learning where the goal is to predict a categorical target variable based on the text. But can you have (or can you obtain) a reasonably large sample of labelled texts labelled with their corresponding category? If not you can't train a supervised model.

Comment: Hi Erwan, Thanks for responding.  I can get a pretty large sample of labelled texts, maybe around 400-600 responses linked to their category.  Thank you for pointing me toward text classification.